# How to calculate uncertanty of extremal point of fitted quadratic polynom?

Tags: fitting, curve-fitting

I am doing some fitting in python, that is:

```
fun = np.array([1.48706e-05, 1.63946e-05, 1.61683e-05, 1.33775e-05])
var = np.array([15.368, 15.504, 15.64 , 15.776])

x = np.linspace (var[0], var[-1], 100)

(a, b, c), cov = np.polyfit(var, fun, 2, cov = True)
a,b,c
(-5.832071799333984e-05, 0.001812880441184612, -0.014071596430063667)

s_a, s_b, s_c = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
s_a, s_b, s_c
(4.9216223166178695e-06, 0.00015328017457825164, 0.0011933529668798418)

plt.scatter (var, fun)
plt.plot (x, a*x**2+b*x+c)
plt.show ()
```

Ok, so I get expected fit:

[image]

Then, I need to calculate the position of the maximum of the poly and its *uncertainty*. First step is easy: $x_{max}(a, b) = -\frac{\overline{b}}{2\overline{a}}\approx 15.54233$.

My attempt for uncertainty is standard error propagation:

[image] $\approx 1.85666$

Problem is that I expected a much smaller value for the uncertainty of $x_{max}$, something like ~0.05. Is my expectation unreasonable or did I made an error in calculation?

Comment: what do you mean with uncertainty?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking. I am trying to calculate the location of maximum of fitted polynomial and its associated uncertainty. My problem is that the obvious way to do it produces uncertainty that is substantially larger than one would expect, or at least me. I came to conclusion that the problem is with error propagation formula which assumes independent variables and poly coef certainly aren't so. So, I'll try mixed term corrections and see what comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, I made an error - polynomial coefficients are not independent variables but correlated parameters and "standard" error propagation is missing a term.

[image]

When cross-correlated (third) term is calculated, uncertainty comes out at expected order.